# jquery if loop using bootstrap classes

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap

I am using twitter bootstrap validation class to get success and error in a text-box. I have two text boxes so when a user clicks on any text-box jquery should first check if the text-box is empty if its empty then red colour should appear around the box. When a user start entering data the text-box should change the colour to green. I would like to apply this technique  across all the text-boxes. This is what I have done but when running a page it is not working?:

```
<div class="test">
    <div class="form-group has-success">
    </div>
        </div>
    <div class="form-group has-error">
    </div>

         <div id="pt" class="tab-pane active">           
                    <asp:Label ID="label1" CssClass="form-group" runat="server" Text="Name:"></asp:Label>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" CssClass="form-control" runat="server" ></asp:TextBox>
                   <asp:Label ID="label2" CssClass="form-group" runat="server" Text="Surname:"></asp:Label>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox2" CssClass="form-control" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>           
  </div>

Jquery

      $("TextBox").click(function () {
            if ($.trim($('TextBox').val()) == "") {
                $('.form-group has-error');
            }
            else if ($.trim($('TextBox').val()) != "") {
                $('.form-group has-success');
            }
         });
```

This is the website i have used to get validation status: [bootstrap example which i am following click here](http://getbootstrap.com/css/) under form -> control status

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
$(function(){
    $("#TextBox1").on("click", function(){
        if($("#TextBox1").val().length === 0){
            $("#TextBox1").parent().addClass("has-error");
        }
    });
    $("#TextBox1").on("keydown", function(){
        if($("#TextBox1").parent().hasClass("has-error")){
            $("#TextBox1").parent().removeClass("has-error");
            $("#TextBox1").parent().addClass("has-success");
        }
    });

    $("#TextBox2").on("click", function(){
        if($("#TextBox2").val().length === 0){
            $("#TextBox2").parent().addClass("has-error");
        }
    });
    $("#TextBox2").on("keydown", function(){
        if($("#TextBox2").parent().hasClass("has-error")){
            $("#TextBox2").parent().removeClass("has-error");
            $("#TextBox2").parent().addClass("has-success");
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: hi, thanks for that, but still its not working? i try adding some data no color or nothing is appearing. dont you think your missing bootstrap class which is  .form-group has-error that sets the border of green and red. this is where i got my example http://getbootstrap.com/css/      under form -> control status

Comment: Hi, check this example: http://jsfiddle.net/fatgamer85/C4qMD/

Is this the behaviour you need?

Comment: thank you for that, it works. But when i enter something it turns into green if i clear the text it still stays green. What i also want is when i remove text it should go back to red colour and also how do i apply this method to all of the text-boxes because i dont want to make my jquery too long.

Comment: Hi, check this update: http://jsfiddle.net/fatgamer85/C4qMD/2/

    The changes I've made is that I started referring to the elements via class name instead of IDs to reduce the code length.

    I've also added common class names to Input elements so that I can refer to all of them at the same time.

    I've also added a else block which would check the length of the input field and change the color back to red when there is nothing present in it.

Hope this helps

Comment: It works. Thank you. Another thing dose this act as a validation?

Comment: It depends on what do you want to do with validation. The code now checks for empty fields and displays the user that the field is empty, it is validation to certain extent. I suggest that you should try [jquery.validation.js](http://github.com/jzaefferer/jquery-validation) plugin to do some validation.. or you could write your own.


hope this helps :)

Answer (score 0):

Your HTML seems to be malformed. 
I am not sure I understood correctly your question, but if you want to display the divs, then your code should work like that:

```
       $("#tbDepartment").click(function () {
            if ($.trim($('#tbDepartment').val()) == "") {
                $('.form-group has-error').show();
            }
            else if ($.trim($('#tbDepartment').val()) != "") {
                $('.form-group has-success').show();
            }
         });
```